# contact forum 7 to static page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, contacts, contact-form-7

I have a static page site in WordPress and I want the "contact me" at the bottom of the page. how would I add that without having a separate page with contact forum 7?    I am adding my custom page into WordPress that I have made from scratch.  I am using vs code for my text editor. I know there should be a way to cut the code from somewhere and add it at the bottom of my page in the contact section just don't know how.

Comment: just use a short code

Comment: like code from scratch or just cut it out of the contact form contact page and add it to my static page?

Comment: Just cut it out of the wordpress plugin. Is your static page hard coded ?

Comment: ya i made it from scratch and followed a youtube video on where to add the php to get it into wordpress. function calls, php get header ect.